# How to pass a null value to a function in VB6?

Tags: function, vb6, null

What I need: to show the user one message. However, sometimes I need to show in a Textbox and other time in a Combobox.

What I have done: I created two function that recieve:
First function
    1. The command that I want to show to user
    2. The name of a Textbox that will include the message

```
function txtfunction(Byval msg as String, Byval txt as Textbox)
```

Second function
    1. The command that I want to show to user
    2. The name of a Combobox that will include the message

```
function cbxfunction(Byval msg as String, Byval cbx as ComboBox)
```

It's working but I'd like to know if it's possible to mix these two functions in just one. For when I call the function i'm allowed to set a null value of one parameter (Textbox or Combobox).

Function that I want:

```
function txtcbxfunction(Byval msg as String, Byval txt as TextBox, Byval cbx as ComboBox)
```

The way that I expect to call:

```
txtcbxfunction("HELLO",nameTextBox, null) 'Message in the TextBox
txtcbxfunction("HELLO",null,nameComboBox) 'Message in the ComboBox
```

Comment: You tagged VBScript but this isn't VBScript.

Comment: oh...sorry...just a moment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TextBox` and `ComboBox` are both part of VB's `Control` class, so you can represent them generically by using a `Control` object.

For example:

```
Function txtcbxfunction(ByVal msg As String, c As Control)
    c.Text = msg  ' Both TextBox and ComboBox have a "Text" property, so this works
End Function
```

And then call it the same way whether you're using a `TextBox` or a `ComboBox`:

```
txtcbxfunction "Test Message", Text1
txtcbxfunction "Test Message", ComboBox1
```

If you want to ensure that only `TextBox` and `ComboBox` controls are passed to your function, you can use the `TypeName()` function to determine the type of control:

```
Function txtcbxfunction(ByVal msg As String, c As Control)
    Select Case TypeName(c)
        Case "TextBox", "ComboBox"
            c.Text = msg
        Case Else
            Exit Function
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: It 's a good idea to change the title of the question, isn't?

Comment: I can take care of that.

Comment: No problem. Good luck.